# Grammatical correctness of the given sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Refer to the following sentence from a research article.

> This significantly increased complexity in muscle recruitment strategy beyond the activation as pure ankle plantar/dorsiflexors, suggests that in healthy children co-contractions are likely functional to further physiological tasks as balance improvement and control of joint stability.

The first part *"This significantly ....dorsiflexors,* seems to make sense. But the remaining part seems odd. Is there any grammatical mistake with the sentence? May I know the rules it implies/breaks?

Comment: I think the sentence is grammatically correct, but it's very complicated, and I've had to read it several times to parse it.  I think it's basically: **This** (noun) **suggests that** (prepositional-phrase) (nouns) **are likely** (adjective-phrase).  It's a tough sentence partly because a lot of the words in it could either be verbs or participles (*increased*), or adjectives or verbs (*further*).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, @stangdon. Do you think this is a job for ELU.SE?

Comment: I don't get "beyond the activation *as* pure ankle plantar/dorsiflexors". Seems to me like it should use *activation of*, but being such technical jargon maybe not. You should try to elaborate on what you think may be wrong.

Comment: @user3169 I thought about that too, but then "* suggests that...*" would make totally no sense if that's the case.  (Who do these guys write an article for anyway?)